# Mac OS Sierra Feedback app came out of nowhere

Tags: mac, applications, macos, virus

So I was just using my mac normally until I looked at the dock and saw a feedback app (which I didn't open). I thought it was from google due to the material icon design but I cannot find a source that says it is.

I looked at the launchpad and saw the same feedback app.

I wanna know wether this is some sort of malicious app or it's nothing to worry about at all. One thing for sure is that it came out of nowhere.

Edit : Forgot to tell you that the file does not show up in the applications folder (even with showing hidden files on) neither does anything happen when I launch it.

[image]

Comment: Can you go to Apple menu → About This Mac and check the exact version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Sierra version 10.12.6

Comment: Certainly worth proceeding with caution. There is a macOS feedback app provided by Apple (in /System/Library/Core Services/Applications), but it's called "Feedback Assistant" and has a different icon. Are you saying that even if you right click it in the dock and select "Options>Show in Finder", a Finder window opens (showing which folder?) but it's not there?

Comment: @calum_b I haven't tried it yet and I don't wanna open it anymore so right now I'm just scanning using malwarebytes

Comment: Fair enough. (Though "Show in Finder" should be safe enough in itself, provided you don't click on the app itself after that.)

Comment: @calum_b Just finished a malwarebytes scan and all I got was a few adware chrome extensions, besides that Feedback didn't show up.

Comment: Got the same on Mojave. The app is related to Chrome, as it was in a subfolder on my pc. I did not open it though, just dragged it into the trash bin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a malicious app.  Try downloading Malwarebytes from online to remove it.  Or search for "feedback" in finder to try and locate the app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please [edit] your answer to provide supporting info as to why you think this is malicious software.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in `~/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Feedback.app`, Delete it if you want.